# Avoiding code repeating in RESTful APIS PHP

Tags: php, api, rest

Since my last [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164846/mvc-structured-rest-api-in-php) related to this I have managed to create a working base and to understand how MVC works.

I'm writing **REST**ful APIS in PHP, they serve the purpose but I see that my code is repeating.

For example, for each action, I have a *controller*, a *service*... etc and a lot of that code can be reused not that I write a ton of code for one simple route.

I have tried a few of my ideas but I end up having spaghetti code and it does not look clean.

---

Here is folder the structure in one of my APIS.

```
.
├── README.md
├── apache_default
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
│   ├── config-development.yml
│   ├── config-production.yml
│   ├── dependencies
│   │   ├── common
│   │   │   ├── cashing.yml
│   │   │   ├── components.yml
│   │   │   ├── controllers.yml
│   │   │   ├── domains.yml
│   │   │   ├── middleware.yml
│   │   │   ├── objmap.yml
│   │   │   ├── repositories.yml
│   │   │   └── services.yml
│   │   ├── development
│   │   │   └── db.yml
│   │   ├── general-production.yml
│   │   ├── general.yml
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── parameters
│   │   └── development
│   │       └── tables.yml
│   └── routing.yml
├── phpunit.xml
├── public
│   ├── Bootstrap.php
│   ├── Kernel.php
│   ├── index.php
│   └── monolog.log
├── resources
│   ├── git
│   │   ├── diagram.png
│   │   ├── schema.png
│   │   └── schema_1.png
│   └── loggs
│       └── monolog.txt
├── src
│   └── Spartan
│       ├── Core
│       │   ├── Component
│       │   │   ├── Collection.php
│       │   │   ├── Controller.php
│       │   │   ├── DataMapper.php
│       │   │   ├── Exception.php
│       │   │   ├── MapperFactory.php
│       │   │   └── Service.php
│       │   ├── Database
│       │   │   ├── ES.php
│       │   │   └── PDOCompat.php
│       │   ├── Entities
│       │   │   ├── CanPersistMapper.php
│       │   │   ├── HasId.php
│       │   │   └── ResponseBootstrap.php
│       │   ├── Logger
│       │   │   └── Logger.php
│       │   └── Mapper
│       │       └── CanCreateMapper.php
│       ├── Models
│       │   ├── Adapters
│       │   ├── Cashing
│       │   │   └── WorkoutCashing.php
│       │   ├── Collections
│       │   │   ├── DescriptionCollection.php
│       │   │   ├── ExerciseCollection.php
│       │   │   ├── NameCollection.php
│       │   │   ├── RoundCollection.php
│       │   │   ├── TagCollection.php
│       │   │   ├── WorkoutCollection.php
│       │   │   └── WorkoutListCollection.php
│       │   ├── Domains
│       │   │   ├── AddWorkoutDomain
│       │   │   │   └── AddWorkoutDomain.php
│       │   │   ├── DeleteWorkoutDomain
│       │   │   │   └── DeleteWorkoutDomain.php
│       │   │   ├── EditWorkoutDomain
│       │   │   │   └── EditWorkoutDomain.php
│       │   │   ├── GetWorkoutDomain
│       │   │   │   └── GetWorkoutDomain.php
│       │   │   ├── GetWorkoutIdsDomain
│       │   │   │   └── GetWorkoutIdsDomain.php
│       │   │   ├── GetWorkoutListDomain
│       │   │   │   └── GetWorkoutListDomain.php
│       │   │   ├── ReleaseWorkoutDomain
│       │   │   │   └── ReleaseWorkoutDomain.php
│       │   │   └── WorkoutExsistsDomain
│       │   │       └── WorkoutExsistsDomain.php
│       │   ├── Entities
│       │   │   ├── Description.php
│       │   │   ├── Exercise.php
│       │   │   ├── Name.php
│       │   │   ├── Round.php
│       │   │   ├── Tag.php
│       │   │   ├── Version.php
│       │   │   ├── Workout.php
│       │   │   └── WorkoutList.php
│       │   ├── Exceptions
│       │   │   ├── BaseError.php
│       │   │   ├── DescriptionConfliect.php
│       │   │   ├── ESError.php
│       │   │   ├── NameConflict.php
│       │   │   ├── RoundError.php
│       │   │   └── TagError.php
│       │   ├── Facades
│       │   ├── Helpers
│       │   ├── Interfaces
│       │   │   └── CanPersistWorkout.php
│       │   ├── Mappers
│       │   │   ├── VersionMapper.php
│       │   │   ├── WorkoutBase.php
│       │   │   ├── WorkoutDescription.php
│       │   │   ├── WorkoutListMapper.php
│       │   │   ├── WorkoutName.php
│       │   │   ├── WorkoutRound.php
│       │   │   └── WorkoutTag.php
│       │   ├── Middlewares
│       │   │   ├── CreateWorkoutMiddleware.php
│       │   │   ├── DeleteWorkoutMiddleware.php
│       │   │   ├── EditWorkoutMiddleware.php
│       │   │   ├── GetWorkoutByIdsMiddleware.php
│       │   │   ├── GetWorkoutListMiddleware.php
│       │   │   ├── GetWorkoutMiddleware.php
│       │   │   └── ReleaseWorkoutMiddleware.php
│       │   ├── Repositories
│       │   │   └── WorkoutRepository.php
│       │   └── Services
│       │       └── WorkoutService.php
│       └── Presentation
│           ├── Controller
│           │   ├── LogController.php
│           │   └── WorkoutController.php
│           └── Mappers
│               └── WorkoutMapp.php
└── tests
    ├── bootstrap.php
    ├── fixture
    ├── integration
    ├── mock
    │   ├── Entity.php
    │   ├── Factory.php
    │   ├── Mapper.php
    │   ├── RepoEntity.php
    │   └── RepoMapper.php
    ├── report
    └── unit
        └── Spartan
            ├── Cashing
            │   └── WorkoutCashingTest.php
            ├── Component
            │   ├── CollectionTest.php
            │   ├── DataMapperTest.php
            │   └── MapperFactoryTest.php
            ├── Controller
            │   └── MappTest.php
            ├── Domains
            ├── Entities
            │   ├── DescriptionTest.php
            │   ├── ExerciseTest.php
            │   ├── NameTest.php
            │   ├── RoundTest.php
            │   ├── TagTest.php
            │   ├── VersionTest.php
            │   ├── WorkoutListTest.php
            │   └── WorkoutTest.php
            ├── Mappers
            │   ├── VersionTest.php
            │   ├── WorkoutBaseTest.php
            │   ├── WorkoutDescriptionTest.php
            │   ├── WorkoutListTest.php
            │   ├── WorkoutNameTest.php
            │   ├── WorkoutRoundTest.php
            │   └── WorkoutTagTest.php
            ├── Repositories
            │   └── WorkoutTest.php
            └── Services
                └── WorkoutTest.php
```

For each activity I have a controller, that controller has a service injected into it via DI over yml.

When the service loads I have a domain folder where I keep my logic and over a factory, I create mappers there which I need(if I need them).

Each domain does one action, for example version workout(I need this for auditing of my data in MySQL).

Than I have a middleware in my service which does cashing(I'm working to change)

And thats basically how each of my routes works a lot of repeated code.

It looks very boring to write code now and I need a push into another direction.

---

Here is a part of my code:

index.php

```
<?php

//Display errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// load vendor
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../public/Kernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../public/Bootstrap.php';

// new kernel
$kernel = new Kernel('dev');
$bootstrap = new Bootstrap;

// new request
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// loader interface
$config = $kernel->registerContainerConfiguration();
// response from
$response = $bootstrap->handle($request,$config,null);
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php
class Bootstrap
{

    public function handle($request,$config,$ipRange)
    {        


        // Configuration 
        $locator = new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../config');
        $data = new ResponseBootstrap();


        // Create a log channel
        $log = new Logger('spartan_workouts_ms');
        $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('monolog.log'));
        $log->pushHandler(new LogglyHandler('55920048-11f0-4b7e-a203-e90083d6962d/tag/monolog', Logger::INFO));


        // Dependency Injection Container
        $container = new DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
        $loader = new DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, $locator);
        $loader->load($config);
        $container->compile();


        // Routing
        $loader = new Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader($locator);
        $context = new Routing\RequestContext();
        $context->fromRequest($request);
        $matcher = new Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher(
            $loader->load('routing.yml'),
            $context
        );


        try{
            $parameters = $matcher->match($request->getPathInfo());
            foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
                $request->attributes->set($key, $value);
            }
            $command = $request->getMethod() . $request->get('action');
            $resource = "controller.{$request->get('controller')}";
            $controller = $container->get($resource);
            $data = $controller->{$command}($request);     
        }
        // log custom thrown exceptions
        catch (\Exception $e) {

            /**
             * This is to slow it takes to much time to log
             */
//             // log errors
//             $log->addWarning(
//                     json_encode([
//                         "date"=> date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
//                         "code"=> $e->getCode(),
//                         "message"=> $e->getMessage(),
//                         "file"=> $e->getFile(),
//                         "line"=> $e->getLine()
//                     ])
//                 );

            $data->setData([
                "date"=> date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
                "code"=> $e->getCode(),
                "message"=> $e->getMessage(),
                "file"=> $e->getFile(),
                "line"=> $e->getLine()
            ]);

            if($e->getCode() == 0){
                // TODO log data
                $data->setStatus(404);
            }else{
                // TODO log data
                $data->setStatus($e->getCode());
            }
            $data->setMessage($e->getMessage());


            //echo "log to monolog";
        } catch (\TypeError $error) {
            // TODO log data
            $data->setStatus(404);
            $data->setMessage(new Response("Invalid dependency: {$error->getMessage()}"));
            die(print_r(new Response("Invalid dependency: {$error->getMessage()}")));
        }


        // Check if json in array from
        if(!empty($data->getData())){
            $response = new JsonResponse($data->getData());
        }else{
            // Not json
            $response = new Response;
        }


        //Set custom headers
        $response->setStatusCode(
            (int)$data->getStatus(),
            empty($data->getMessage()) ? $data->getMessage() : null
            );


        // preflighted request handle
        if($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS'){
            // set status
            $response->setStatusCode((int)200);
        }


        // headers
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");


        // return response
        $response->send();


        return $response;
    }

}
```

Kernel.php

```
<?php
class Kernel
{

    protected $env;

    public function __construct($env = null)
    {
        if (is_null($env)) {
            $this->env = is_null($env) ? 'prod' : 'dev';
        }else{
            $this->env = $env;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads the container configuration.
     */
    public function registerContainerConfiguration()
    {
        if((string)$this->env === (string)'dev'){
            $configuration = 'config-development.yml';
        }else{
            $configuration = 'config-production.yml';
        }
        return $configuration;
    }

}
```

WorkoutController.php

```
<?php
class WorkoutController extends Controller
{


    private $workoutService;
    private $workoutMapp;


    public function __construct(WorkoutService $workoutService, WorkoutMapp $workoutMapp){

        $this->workoutService = $workoutService;
        $this->workoutMapp = $workoutMapp;

        // construct the parent
        parent::__construct();
    }


    /**
     * Get workout
     * Get workouts by id
     * Get workout list
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return ResponseBootstrap
     */
    public function get(Request $request):ResponseBootstrap
    {
        $workout = $this->workoutMapp->getWorkoutUniversal($request);

        // list
        if(!is_null($workout->getOffset()) && !is_null($workout->getLimit()) && !is_null($workout->getState())){
            return $this->workoutService->getWorkoutList($workout);
        }
        // get workout by id
        if($workout->getId() && $workout->getState()){
            return $this->workoutService->getWorkout($workout);
        }
        // get workout ids
        if($workout->getIds()){
            return $this->workoutService->getWorkoutIds($workout);
        }


        return $this->badRequest();
    }


    /**
     * Create workout
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return ResponseBootstrap
     */
    public function post(Request $request)
    {
        // raw data
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        // map raw data to workout object
        $workout = $this->workoutMapp->addWorkout($data);


        // check if the name, description, tags and rounds are not empty
        if(!empty($workout->getNames()->toArray()) && !empty($workout->getDescriptions()->toArray()) && !empty($workout->getTags()->toArray()) && !empty($workout->getRounds()->toArray())){
            return $this->workoutService->addWorkout($workout);
        }

        // when empty return a response from the base controller
        return $this->badRequest();
    }
....
```

WorkoutService.php

```
<?php
class WorkoutService extends Service
{

    ......

    /**
     * Add Workout
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return ResponseBootstrap
     */
    public function addWorkout(Workout $workout):ResponseBootstrap
    {                       
        // middleware for handling cashing
        $this->createWorkoutMiddleware->handle(
            $this->addWorkoutDomain, 
            $workout, 
            $this->getWorkoutDomain);

        return $this->formResponse($workout, true);
    }


    /**
     * Delete Workout
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return ResponseBootstrap
     */
    public function deleteWorkout(Workout $workout):ResponseBootstrap
    {        
        // middleware for handling cashing
        $this->deleteWorkoutMiddleware->handle(
            $this->deleteWorkoutDomain,
            $workout);

        return $this->formResponse($workout, false);
    }


    /**
     * Edit Workout
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return ResponseBootstrap
     */
    public function editWorkout(Workout $workout):ResponseBootstrap
    {        
        // middleware for handling cashing
        $this->editWorkoutMiddleware->handle(
            $this->editWorkoutDomain,
            $workout,
            $this->getWorkoutDomain);

        return $this->formResponse($workout, false);
    }
```

WorkoutRepository.php

```
<?php    
class WorkoutRepository implements CanPersistWorkout
{

    private $mapperFactory;
    private $list = [
        Workout::class => WorkoutBase::class,
        Round::class => WorkoutRound::class,
        Name::class => WorkoutName::class,
        Version::class => VersionMapper::class,
        Description::class => WorkoutDescription::class,
        Tag::class => WorkoutTag::class,
        RoundCollection::class => WorkoutRound::class,
        NameCollection::class => WorkoutName::class,
        DescriptionCollection::class => WorkoutDescription::class,
        TagCollection::class => WorkoutTag::class,
        WorkoutListCollection::class => WorkoutListMapper::class
    ];


    public function __construct(CanCreateMapper $mapperFactory)
    {
        $this->mapperFactory = $mapperFactory;
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /************************************     Store         **************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    public function storeDescription(Description $description, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($description), $override);
        $mapper->store($description);
    }


    public function storeBase(Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($workout), $override);
        $mapper->store($workout);
    }


    public function storeRound(Round $round, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($round), $override);
        $mapper->store($round);
    }


    public function storeName(Name $name, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($name), $override);
        $mapper->store($name);
    }


    public function versionUp(Version $version, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($version), $override);
        $mapper->versionUp($version);
    }

    public function storeTag(Tag $tag, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($tag), $override);
        $mapper->store($tag);
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /************************************     Delete        **************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    public function deleteWorkout(Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($workout), $override);
        $mapper->delete($workout);
    }


    public function deleteRounds(Round $round, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($round), $override);
        $mapper->delete($round,$workout);
    }


    public function deleteDescriptions(Description $description, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($description), $override);
        $mapper->delete($description,$workout);
    }


    public function deleteNames(Name $name, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($name), $override);
        $mapper->delete($name,$workout);
    }


    public function deleteTags(Tag $tag, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($tag), $override);
        $mapper->delete($tag,$workout);
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /************************************     Fetch         **************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    public function getDescriptions(DescriptionCollection $description, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($description), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($description, $workout);
    }


    public function getRounds(RoundCollection $round, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($round), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($round, $workout);
    }


    public function getNames(NameCollection $name, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($name), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($name,$workout);
    }


    public function getWorkout(Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($workout), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($workout);
    }


    public function getTags(TagCollection $tag, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($tag), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($tag, $workout);
    }


    public function getWorkoutList(WorkoutListCollection $list, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($list), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($list, $workout);
    }


    public function getTotalWorkotus(Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($workout), $override);
        $mapper->total($workout);
    }



    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /***********************************     Update   ********************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    public function updateNameState(NameCollection $name, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($name), $override);
        $mapper->update($name, $workout);
    }


    public function updateRoundState(RoundCollection $round, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($round), $override);
        $mapper->update($round,$workout);
    }


    public function updateBaseState(Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($workout), $override);
        $mapper->update($workout);
    }


    public function updateDescriptionState(DescriptionCollection $description, Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($description), $override);
        $mapper->update($description,$workout);
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /***********************************     Audit    ********************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    public function auditRound(Round $round,Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($round), $override);
        $mapper->storeToAudit($round, $workout);
    }


    public function auditDescription(Description $description,Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($description), $override);
        $mapper->storeToAudit($description, $workout);
    }


    public function auditBase(Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($workout), $override);
        $mapper->storeToAudit($workout);
    }


    public function auditName(Name $name,Workout $workout, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($name), $override);
        $mapper->storeToAudit($name,$workout);
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /***********************************    Helpers   ********************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    public function begginTransaction()
    {
        $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->create(WorkoutBase::class);
        $mapper->begginTransaction();
    }


    public function commitTransaction()
    {
        $mapper = $this->mapperFactory->create(WorkoutBase::class);
        $mapper->commit();
    }


    private function computeKey(string $key, string $override = null): string
    {
        if ($override !== null) {
            $key = $override;
        }
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->list) === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("No mapper for class '{$key}' has been defined!");
        }
        return $key;
    }


    private function retrieveMapper(string $name, string $override = null)
    {
        $key = $this->computeKey($name, $override);
        $entry = $this->list[$key];
        return $this->mapperFactory->create($entry);
    }



    public function define(string $entity, string $mapper)
    {
        if (class_exists($entity) === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Entity class '{$entity}' was not found!");
        }
        if (class_exists($mapper) === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException("Mapper class '{$mapper}' was not found!");
        }
        $this->list[$entity] = $mapper;
    }


    public function load($identity, string $override = null)
    {
        $mapper = $this->retrieveMapper(get_class($identity), $override);
        $mapper->fetch($identity);
    }


}
```

VersionMapper.php

```
<?php    
class VersionMapper extends DataMapper
{


    /**
     * Version Up
     * 
     * @param Version $version
     */
    public function versionUp(Version $version) // TODO handle exceptions
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO version VALUES(null)";
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        $version->setVersion($this->connection->lastInsertId());
    }


}
```

AddWorkoutDomain.php

```
<?php    
class AddWorkoutDomain
{


    private $repository;


    public function __construct(Repository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /*****************************    Visible functions to children ******************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    /**
     * Handle 
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return array
     */
    public function handle(Workout $workout):array
    {
        // beggin transaction
        $this->repository->begginTransaction();

        $messages = [];

        $messages = array_merge($messages, $this->storeBase($workout));
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $this->storeNames($workout));
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $this->storeDescriptions($workout));
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $this->storeRounds($workout));
        $messages = array_merge($messages, $this->storeTags($workout));

        // commit transaction
        $this->repository->commitTransaction();

        return $messages;
    }


    /**
     * Get Total
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     */
    public function getTotal(Workout $workout):void
    {
        $this->repository->getTotalWorkotus($workout);
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /*************************************  Executors   ******************************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    /**
     * Store Base
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return array
     */
    private function storeBase(Workout $workout):array
    {        
        // version up
        $workout->setVersion($this->versionUp()->getVersion());
        $workout->setState('P');

        $this->repository->storeBase($workout);

        return ['success'=>'Base'];
    }


    /**
     * Store Names
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return array
     */
    private function storeNames(Workout $workout):array
    {
        foreach($workout->getNames()->toArray() as $name){
            // set workout parent
            $name->setParent($workout->getId());
            $name->setState('P');

            $this->repository->storeName($name);
        }

        return ['success'=>'Names'];
    }


    /**
     * Store Descriptions
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return array
     */
    private function storeDescriptions(Workout $workout):array
    {
        foreach($workout->getDescriptions()->toArray() as $description){
            // set workout parent
            $description->setParent($workout->getId());
            $description->setState('P');

            $this->repository->storeDescription($description);
        }

        return ['success'=>'Descriptions'];
    }


    /**
     * Store Rounds
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return array
     */
    private function storeRounds(Workout $workout):array
    {
        foreach($workout->getRounds()->toArray() as $round){
            // set workout parent
            $round->setParent($workout->getId());
            $round->setState('P');

            $this->repository->storeRound($round);
        }

        return ['success'=>'Rounds'];
    }


    /**
     * Store Tags
     * 
     * @param Workout $workout
     * @return array
     */
    private function storeTags(Workout $workout):array
    {
        foreach($workout->getTags()->toArray() as $tag){
            // set workout parent
            $tag->setParent($workout->getId());

            $this->repository->storeTag($tag);
        }

        return ['success'=>'Rounds'];
    }


    /**
     * Version Up
     * 
     * @return Version
     */
    private function versionUp():Version
    {
        $version = new Version();
        $this->repository->versionUp($version);

        return $version;
    }


}
```

Any comment and advice are welcome, I'm seeking to expand my knowledge.

Credits to [Tereško](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/tere%C5%A1ko) for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered my question probably because I have not explained what I want here is an answer which satisfied my needs.

I have been wondering in the dark than I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937586/generic-programming-vs-metaprogramming) which expanded my knowledge regarding programming.

I have seen some of those methods but I have never taught of the level of abstraction which they can bring.

As the accepted answer states:

> Programming: Writing a program that creates, transforms, filters,
>   aggregates and otherwise manipulates data.
>
> Metaprogramming: Writing a program that creates, transforms, filters,
>   aggregates and otherwise manipulates programs.
>
> Generic Programming: Writing a program that creates, transforms,
>   filters, aggregates and otherwise manipulates data, but makes only the
>   minimum assumptions about the structure of the data, thus maximizing
>   reuse across a wide range of data types.

I saw that I have been typing code which can be easily avoided.

Long story short here is my implementation to the issue I had.

---

My controller is still not there where I want it to be but I have managed to call my actions like this:

```
   return $this->baseService->actionHandler($exercise,
        [
            BaseService::ACT_GET_NAME,
            BaseService::ACT_GET_DESC,
            BaseService::ACT_GET_BASE,
            BaseService::ACT_GET_OBJ
        ],
        $queryParams
    );
```

And my service looks something like this:

```
class BaseService
{

    // vars
    private $domainRepository;
    private $responseBootstrap;
    private $versionDomain;
    private $nameDomain;
    private $tagDomain;
    private $planDomain;
    private $packageDomain;
    private $roundDomain;
    private $auditDomain;
    private $deleteDomain;
    private $languageDomain;


    //actions create
    const ACT_VERSION = 'versionUp';
    const ACT_CREATE = 'createObject';
    const ACT_SINGLE_OBJ = 'returnSingleObject';
    const ACT_CRE_NAME = 'createName';
    const ACT_CRE_DESC = 'createDescription';
    const ACT_CRE_TAG = 'createTags';
    const ACT_CRE_BODY = 'createBody';
    const ACT_CRE_PKG_PLAN = 'createPackagePlan';
    const ACT_CRE_WRK_PLN_DAY = 'createWorkoutPlanDay';
    const ACT_CRE_ROUND = 'createRound';
    const ACT_RELEASE = 'releaseContent';
    const ACT_DELETE = 'delete';

    // actions delete 
    const ACT_ED_NAME = 'editName';
    const ACT_ED_OBJ = 'editObject';
    const ACT_ED_DESC = 'editDescription';
    const ACT_ED_TAG = 'editTag';
    const ACT_ED_ROUND = 'editRound';
    const ACT_ED_BODY = 'editBody';
    const ACT_ED_DAY = 'editDay';
    const ACT_ED_PKG_PLAN = 'editPackagePlan';

    // actions get
    const ACT_GET_NAME = 'getName';
    const ACT_GET_DESC = 'getDescription';
    const ACT_GET_BODY = 'getBody';
    const ACT_GET_OBJ = 'getObjectResponse';
    const ACT_GET_BASE = 'getBase';

    // system actions
    const SYS_ACT_BEG_TRANS = 'begginTransaction';
    const SYS_ACT_COM_TRANS = 'commitTransaction';
    const SYS_ACT_ROLB_TRANS = 'rollbackTransaction';

    private $responseArray = [];



    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param DomainRepository $domainRepository
     * @param ResponseBootstrap $responseBootstrap
     * @param VersionDomain $versionDomain
     * @param NameDomain $nameDomain
     * @param NameDomain $descriptionDomain
     */

    public function __construct(
        DomainRepository $domainRepository,
        ResponseBootstrap $responseBootstrap,
        VersionDomain $versionDomain,
        NameDomain $nameDomain,
        TagDomain $tagDomain,
        PlanDomain $planDomain,
        PackageDomain $packageDomain,
        RoundDomain $roundDomain,
        AuditDomain $auditDomain,
        DeleteDomain $deleteDomain, 
        LanguageDomain $languageDomain)
    {
        $this->domainRepository = $domainRepository;
        $this->responseBootstrap = $responseBootstrap;
        $this->versionDomain = $versionDomain;
        $this->nameDomain = $nameDomain;
        $this->tagDomain = $tagDomain;
        $this->planDomain = $planDomain;
        $this->packageDomain = $packageDomain;
        $this->roundDomain = $roundDomain;
        $this->auditDomain = $auditDomain;
        $this->deleteDomain = $deleteDomain;
        $this->languageDomain = $languageDomain;
    }


    /**
     * Action Handler
     * 
     * @param object $object
     * @param array $actions
     * @return object
     */
    public function actionHandler(object $object, array $actions = [], QueryParams $queryParams = null):object
    {
        try{
            // beggin transaction
            $this->domainRepository->begginTransaction();

            foreach($actions as $action){
                // on create return object
                if($action == BaseService::ACT_SINGLE_OBJ){
                    // commit transaction
                    $this->domainRepository->commitTransaction(); 
                    return $this->{$action}($object);
                }
                // on get return object
                else if($action == BaseService::ACT_GET_OBJ){
                    // commit transaction
                    $this->domainRepository->commitTransaction();

                    return $this->{$action}();
                }else{
                    $this->{$action}($object, $queryParams);
                }
            } 
        }catch(\PDOException $e){
            // handle rollback of sql action
            $this->domainRepository->rollbackTransaction($e);
        }
    }


    /*********************************************************************************************/
    /***********************************         Executors       *********************************/
    /*********************************************************************************************/


    /**
     * Version Up
     * 
     * @param object $object
     */
    private function versionUp(object $object):void
    {
        // version up
        $this->versionDomain->handle($object);
    }

    ...........
```

The **BaseService** class has all the actions and it calls the DAO layer which is flexible enough to construct the query I need.

I need to add a caching layer to it and a few more things but this is the answer which I have been asking for(at least I think so if somebody else had a better version of it feel free to post your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Take the following `Kernel` class:

```
class Kernel
{
    protected $env;

    const ENV_TYPE_DEV = 'dev';
    const ENV_TYPE_PROD = 'prod';

    public function __construct($env = null)
    {
        $this->env = $env ?? self::ENV_TYPE_DEV;
    }

    /**
    * Loads the container configuration.
    */
    public function registerContainerConfiguration()
    {
        if ($this->env === self::ENV_TYPE_DEV) {
            $configuration = 'config-development.yml';
        } else {
            $configuration = 'config-production.yml';
        }

        return $configuration;
    }
}
```

The changes I made are as follows:

- Defined two constants so you can reference them rather than passing a direct string as the `$env`. This also gives you the option to change the values in the future without having to consider hardcoded versions of the values
- Simplified your `if` statement (via the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)) in your `__construct` to set the `$env` property to whatever is passed to `ENV_TYPE_DEV` as a default
- In `registerContainerConfiguration` I removed your casts as they were redundant and turned the hard-coded string into the respective `const`

Then your `index.php` file:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// load vendor
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// autoloading done through composer
// error handling based on kernel env
// type that is passed.

// new kernel
$kernel = new Kernel(Kernel::ENV_TYPE_DEV);
$bootstrap = new Bootstrap;

// new request
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// loader interface
$config = $kernel->registerContainerConfiguration();
// response from
$response = $bootstrap->handle($request, $config, null);
```

The changes I made / suggest are as follows:

- You should have your error reporting work in conjunction with your environment that is defined in your `Kernel`
- You should autoload your classes through composer
- I changed the hardcoded `dev` string to the defined constant

In your `AddWorkoutDomain` class, I'd simplify the handle function:

```
/**
  * Handle 
  * 
  * @param Workout $workout
  * @return array
  */
  public function handle(Workout $workout):array
  {
      // beggin transaction
      $this->repository->begginTransaction();

      $messages = array_merge($messages, $this->storeBase($workout), $this->storeNames($workout), $this->storeDescriptions($workout), $this->storeRounds($workout), $this->storeTags($workout));

      // commit transaction
      $this->repository->commitTransaction();

      return $messages;
  }
```

- Merged the [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) calls into one (pun intended...), as per the documentation, the second parameter can be a list of variables to merge, doesn't have to be one per function call

### Miscellaneous

- Opinionated but, you seem to have quite a few blank lines within your classes, I would reduce that down
- In various places you check for `null` variables in long, drawn out, if statements:

  ```
  if(!is_null($workout->getOffset()) && !is_null($workout->getLimit()) && !is_null($workout->getState())){
      return $this->workoutService->getWorkoutList($workout);
  }
  ```

Consider the following:

```
if (isset($workout->getOffset(), $workout->getLimit(), $workout->getState())) {

}
```

Comment: I have implemented your changes, thank you!

I won't accept your answer but I will upvote it.

If you could go through the whole code and give me full feedback on my code and classes and how it can be reduced I will accept it then.